# position is not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

```
  <lightning-card>   
  <div style="position:relative">
      <img  src={pic1} style="top: 0px; left: 0px;">
      <img  src={pic2} style="position:absolute;top: 90px; left: 20px; border-radius: 50%;"/>
  </div>
  <div style="top: 2000px;">
      record id:{recordId}
</lightning-card>
```

I am trying to insert 2 images one inside other. The UI looks like our social profile. One background image and profile picture in front left corner. With the below code images are got placed properly but other tags are not populating properly in UI. like record id is getting printed behind the Pic2 and i am not able to move it down or other place. pls help here.

Comment: Why dont you use GRIDS for showing it side by side?

Comment: Note that Salesforce don't like the use of "position" CSS/styling without the container including one of the [SLDS positioning styles](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/position/).